# trying to divide 16 bit by 16 bit in TASM

Tags: assembly, tasm, emu8086

I have ax, a 16 bit register, and `bx`, also a 16 bit register, I want to divide them and get the result as `dx`,`ax` where dx is the remainder, and ax is the quotient, in Emu8086, doing that works. But in TASM it doesn't. How does emu do the divisions? I want to find a workaround, or atleast make a new `proc` with Emu's division process.

Does anyone know how I can make a workaround that? Or does anyone know how emu8086 does the 16 by 16 bit division, Do I just remove from the dividend the divisor and increment a register every time it happens until the divisor is above the dividend?

Comment: both emu and TASM will use the same intel instruction, there's no problem with that. There may be a problem that there is no 16 by 16 bit division in x86 CPU, so you are using something different by accident (most likely 32 bit `dx:ax` divided by 16 bit `bx`), and by accident it works under emu8086 (`dx` is zero), and it does not in DOS/dosbox/whatever_you_use_with_TASM (`dx` is non zero): http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html

Comment: oh, Ok thanks! appreciate it Fixed!